# How to debug or log some special variables in Craft CMS? (Especially in a controller)

Tags: craft3, php

I am going to debug the variables in controller files.

But I couldn't figure out how I can debug it and show the values into front-end site or in log files.

Do you have any ideas about this?

What is your debug mode which you often use when you work in a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use for example the `dd()` method with the [craft3-dumper](https://github.com/studioespresso/craft3-dumper) package.
You can also use the [debug toolbar](https://nystudio107.com/blog/profiling-your-website-with-craft-cms-3s-debug-toolbar).
You could also use [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to get a nice overview about your errors with the [craft sentry package](https://github.com/lukeyouell/craft-sentry).
Or you could use [xdebug](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-phpstorm-with-vagrant-homestead). Or or or ... :)

So there are severals ways to debug something.

Comment: Note that xdebug (with PHPStorm) is by far the most powerful of these options, and will save you a lot of time. Highly recommended.

Comment: Hey Chris, Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to log the variables without using like UI tools and additional packages? Like var_dump in php.

Comment: Btw, one thing quickly, I have never used PHPstorm, is it a free IDE? :0

Comment: For a quick debug use the craft3-dumper package. I am using this a lot too. And in your controller you can just dd($var); like within laravel for example. PHPStorm is not free, but it's one of the best IDE's out there for PHP development in my opinion

Comment: Thanks, Chris, make sense!